# Angular NgRX action not recognized

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

I have created Angular application using NgRX. I have added actions, reducers, services and effects. But  while access the action got the below error in component code.

> Error: Property 'GetEmployees' does not exist on type 'typeof EmployeeAction'.

find the below code snippets:

In EmployeeComponent:

`this.store.dispatch(new EmployeeAction.GetEmployees());`

employee-actions.ts:

```
export class GetEmployees implements Action {
  readonly type = GET_EMPLOYEES;
}

The entire App code will be available in this Github repository.

https://github.com/techvenky/AngularNgRx/tree/master/src
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you import abstract class and try to create instance of its property.
`GetEmployees` it is a class, import it and turn to it.
So, your dispatch must be like this:
`this.store.dispatch(new GetEmployees());`

And also I recommend you to remove `readonly` from payload properties in constructors of action classes.

Comment: i also thought same and changed the code as you mentioned. now its working fine.